# change existing used field name in SF

Tags: custom-field

Sometimes, I need to change the existing custom field name which is currently using.
There are a lot of places using that field in coding etc.

So basically, system doesn't allow us to change the field name.

How can I manage that kind of situation without causing any troubles to the existing system?
What kind of approach should I take?

I don't want to lose the existing data too.

Please share us your ideas or approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the only way to do this is to comment out all references to that field in your code and pages, rename it, and then uncomment and change the code references. It's painful but really the only option.

That said, do you really need to change the name of the field? Is changing the label of the field not enough?

Comment: Thanks for the approach. For now, I only changed the label of the field like you have mentioned too because it only effects for front end user.  However if we want to change the field name , how should we handle for deployment to production too? need to deploy the commented code. then need to change the field, then deploy the correct code?

Comment: yes right.First move the commented code so that allows you to change the field name and then uncomment and redeploy the code.Thanks